# Converting int to boolean ADO.NET SqlParameter

Tags: c#, ado.net, int, boolean, sqlparameter

I am trying to use a stored procedure that returns an int. Then I need to convert int to a boolean (success).

```
SqlParameter Return = new SqlParameter(); 
Return.ParameterName = "@return";
Return.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
Return.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

However this line of code throws a `System.InvalidCastException` error

```
 Success = (Boolean)Command.Parameters["@return"].Value;
```

What should I do to not get this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following method to do what you need:

```
Success = Convert.ToBoolean(Command.Parameters["@return"].Value);
```

or

```
Success = Command.Parameters["@return"].Value==0?false:true;
```

or

```
if(Command.Parameters["@return"].Value==0)
  Success = false;
else
  Success = true;
```

(they're all the same thing as [Convert.ToBoolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0b8dwce(v=vs.110).aspx) which will be false if the value is zero, otherwise true (this came from C!)

EDIT: one thing I have forgotten is that, if it returns a string or an object, you might have to cast it to integer first before converting to boolean.